# Not able to send email using Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a simple email using a php form and AJAX. However, every time I do, the code throws the `email could not be sent, please try again` error. Why is that happening?

I have also tried to `alert` the variables in the alert sequence, but it did not work. I checked the variables and they seem valid, but it seems that I overlooked something.

**Javascript/jQuery** (in `<head>` block)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$("#form2").submit(function(e){
    $(".error").remove();    
    $('#cancel2').click(function(){          
        return;
    });    

    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    var nameVal = $("#name").val();

    if (nameVal == '') {
        $("#name").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the name.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    var emailToVal = $("#emailTo").val();

    if (emailToVal == '') {
        $("#emailTo").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the email address to send to.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    } else if(!emailReg.test(emailToVal)) {
        $("#emailTo").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address to send to.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    var emailFromVal = $("#emailFrom").val();

    if(emailFromVal == '') {
        $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the email address to send from.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    } else if (!emailReg.test(emailFromVal)) {
        $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address to send from.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    if (hasError == false){
        $('.navLinks').hide();
        $('.navLinks:before').hide();
        $('.navLinks:after').hide();                 
        s                       
        $.ajax({
            "type":"POST",
            "url":"sendemail.php",
            "data": { name: nameVal, emailTo: emailToVal, emailFrom: emailFromVal },
            "dataType":'json',
            "success":function(){
                //$('#sumbit1').after('<img src="/img/wait.gif" alt="wait" />');    
                alert('Your email has been sent! For faster answer please call us at: (403) 454-5526');
                $('.navLinks').hide();    
             },          
             "error": function (){
                 alert('Your email could not be sent, please try again.');
             }    
        });
    }          

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="send-to-friend" id="form2" class="form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <label for="name" class="blockItem">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="blockItem" name="your name" maxlength="60" size="35"/>
    <label for="emailFrom" class="blockItem">Your Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="emailFrom" class="blockItem" name="your email" maxlength="60" size="35" />
    <label for="emailTo" class="blockItem">Your Friend's E-mail Address</label>
    <input  type="text" id="emailTo" class="blockItem" name="your friends email" maxlength="60" size="35"  />
    <input class="button" id="submitt2" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />                               
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$mailTo = $_POST['emailToVal'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['emailFromVal'];
$name = $_POST['nameVal'];
$message = 'I found this company recommended for residential and office cleaning in Calgary. Their website is FineMaid "dot" com (replace "dot", of course in browser\s address bar). Cheers!';  

$subject = $name . ' recommends Fine Maid';

$send = @mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom);    

?>
```

Comment: Is `sendemail.php` in the right directory? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: You're doin it wrong, remove the quotes on the options for $.ajax, look at the examples in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) -

Comment: The script is in the right directory, I also did it without quotes and it did now work, at the suggestion of someone from stack overflow I did it with quotes. And it also throws the error message which I did not think it would it there were no quotes involved.

Comment: You have a random `s` in the code you posted. Also, use `console.log()` with Chrome Console, Firebug in Firefox, or IE9. `alert()`s are not particularly useful for development/debugging purposes. Oh and *do not* use the `@` error suppression operator.

Comment: I would use the full url, e.g., `http://myserver.com/sendmail.php`, just to make sure it's getting to the right location. You can also testing the `sendmail.php` script without AJAX and check to make sure it *will* even send email.

Comment: well I uploaded it on my personal server and some time ago it worked, however I did some changes in the code and now I have this problem...unfortunately I can't remember exactly what I changed. And where is that s in the code that I missed?

Comment: after `$('.navLinks:after').hide();`

Comment: Right above the `$.ajax()` line. Test the `sendmail.php` independently, maybe a `sendmailtest.php` form that ends on `sendmail.php` page. Lose the `@` operator, though. You also probably need to look into the response code from the AJAX to see what you're getting.

Comment: lost the s and it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you access in PHP did not exist, it should be:

```
$mailTo = $_POST['emailTo'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['emailFrom'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

however, you should return a JSON when you use JSON as dataType.

Furthermore: there isn't any check if the mail has been sent, currently jQuery will report a success, when the PHP-script returns a valid JSON(what it doesn't, because the response is at least a single space, or notices for missing POST-variables, not a JSON)

Put this at the end of the script:

```
if(!$send)
{
  header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
}
else
{
 die(json_encode(array('msg'=>'Your email has been sent! 
                               For faster answer please call us at: (403) 454-5526')));
}
```

...when $send is true(the mail has been sended), the script will return a JSON, otherwise the response will have a HTTP-status-code 500, what will trigger the error-callback

Comment: Haha, that's funny. It's often the simplest answer. `:)`

Comment: I know about the check, however I do not know enough JSON to do that, and it is not clear about the values, isn't it emailToVal, etc? I changed the values in the script and it still does now work.